# Order all mysql data by rand then order it by column

Tags: mysql

i have about 1000 records i am querying and ordering by random. Each record has a business type i want to order it by random but then the businesstype. this is my query :

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM businesses where postcode REGEXP '^" . $pcode . "[0-9]' and BusinessID NOT IN (SELECT BusinessID FROM telesales.notinterested WHERE NOW() BETWEEN DateOfCall and (DateOfCall + INTERVAL 42 DAY)) ORDER BY RAND() limit 500";
```

If i do `RAND(), BusinessType` then its just all random still, and if i try group by BusinessType after the Rand it doesnt give any results. Any ideas?

Comment: The second column in order by is only used if the first column (in your case RAND()) is equals what never happends.

Comment: You would change the volumn order in the order by clause. Do rand() last

Comment: Then only the businesses with the same business types are random, i want the list to be randomised and then all the same business types to be grouped together